# Rewrite third covariant derivative

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I have some expression of the form

$$(\nabla_i \nabla^2 f)_{hj}$$

I want to rewrite it, such that I get s.t. like

$$ (\nabla_i \nabla_h \nabla f )_j +??$$

I know that

$$\nabla^2_{ij} f= \nabla_i\nabla_j f - \nabla_{\nabla_i \partial_j} f$$

but I don't know how to use this for my expression.

Comment: Is $\nabla^2f$ the Laplacian of a scalar $f$? If so, the question makes no sense.

Comment: Fix $T = \nabla^2f$, that is, by definition, $T(X,Y) = \nabla_X\nabla_Yf - \nabla_{\nabla_XY}f$. Then by definition, if $X,Y,Z$ are vector fields, then
$$
(\nabla T)(Z;X,Y) = \nabla_Z(T(X,Y)) - T(\nabla_ZX,Y) -T(X,\nabla_ZY).
$$
Can you go on from there ?

Comment: Yes thank you, that helped me!